# Flutter gradle build issues

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I just setup flutter on my ubuntu machine and I get this error when "flutter run" is executed.

This error has been turning around me for hours now.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on TECNO C8 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              0.9s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.2s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.             
> Could not create service of type DefaultUserHomeScopedCompileCaches using UserHomeScopeServices.createCompileCaches().

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 1s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         2.2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think deleting the Caches directory might help, or you can Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: I think this is a gradle dependency issues. Please add your both gradle files here

Answer (score 0):

You can do **File > Invalidate caches and restart**.then try to run once more